Integrate Gnome Software in Unity
I installed the latest Ubuntu Unity. I saw on a video and on other articles that Gnome Software is kind of integrated (has the top bar with the min/max/close buttons, takes the correct dark theme if selected, etc.). But since I installed a minimalistic version of Unity, I had to install gnome-software. Now I have a simple white gnome application that doesn't fit and doesn't even have the window buttons. Is there any way to integrate it again? Maybe some packages I am missing?
